# modify htaccess to extract and remove integer-value from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a htaccess-file like the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?$1=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which directs links like fe "administration/modules" to "index.php/administration=administration&pid=modules" or "administration" to "index.php?pid=administration".

For Performance-Reasons, i would like to modify the htaccess, so it can direct a link like

"administration_55"

to

index.php?pid=55"

so the '55' (the id of the record) would have to get extracted somehow from the pid-parameter "pid=administration_55". As i also would like to have a visible url like "www.example.com/administration" without the "_55" part with it, i wonder, how this would be accomplished in a good way, directly in the htaccess file or in the responding php-file with a header redirect?

Thanx in Advance, Jayden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# e.g. /administration/modules 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?$1=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]
# e.g. /administration_55
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)_([[0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?$1=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]
# e.g. /test
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

As for removing the 55, the best way is to use PHP. I have a separate field called 'url' in my database-table, so I can find the record with the correct url(-part). I also added a Index to this field, for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can doesn't mean you should... Can't you handle this in the index.php of the site itself based on the `REFERRER` additionally which would be more secure and not require the .htaccess support to be enabled...?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect using htaccess but you must have url with _55 part with it